# what time format is this and how to convert it to unix time in php?

Tags: php, paypal, timestamp

`2015-07-01T23:06:30Z` I got this from paypal api. I have never seen this format before what does T and Z stand for. How can I convert this to unix time in php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a date/time in ISO8601 format. The `T` is a delimiter marking the start of the time field, and the `Z` (commonly spoken as 'Zulu') is a common shorthand for GMT or UTC.

It's directly supported by PHP so you can just use `strtotime()`

```
echo strtotime("2015-07-01T23:06:30Z"); // 1435791990
```

[ISO8601 Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=ISO_8601)